# delayedalert. window.onload calling placement

Tags: javascript, function, alert, webcam, timing

I am currently trying to time alerts to appear 3 seconds after the viewer grants permission of the webcam. The alerts are supposed to also have audio with them, as they're supposed to be triggered at the same time.

The webcam has a face tracking feature with it, so there is a lot of extra code.

Previously, I asked this question, and it was answered here; [why are these alerts not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614750/why-are-these-alerts-not-appearing/49614839?noredirect=1#comment86237339_49614839).

Though I had to move some files around in its folder, to collect particular audio files. Which was stupid of me, because now this isn't producing the same outcome as my previous question had answered.

As the previous answer was to move attach the delayedAlert() to the window.onload, now is making the webcam video not appear.

Any suggests to fix this? I don't know javascript, so please visuals help a lot more than statements.

This is the current code I am working with:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>eve_</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/demo.css">
      <link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="../images/evecircle.png" />
      <script src="../build/tracking-min.js"></script>
      <script src="../build/data/face-min.js"></script>
       <script src="../node_modules/dat.gui/build/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <style>
      video, canvas {
        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        position: absolute;
      }
      </style>

       <script>
       var timeoutID;

      function delayedAlert() {
      timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 3000);
    }

    function slowAlert() {
     var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
     const audio2 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
     var audio3 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2];
      var audio4 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[3];

    audio.play(); 
    var myvar1;alert('Oh, there is more of you.');

    audio2.play(); 
    var myvar1;alert('Why are there multiple yous?');

    audio3.play();
    const name = prompt('What is your name?')

    const sentence = 'Hello,' + name +'.I am Eve. ....'+name+name+name+'.'+name+'is human...Ive never seen a. human....What does' +name +' look like?';
    responsiveVoice.speak(sentence, "US English Female", {
        rate: 0.7}
      </script>

      <script>
          window.onload = function() {
          var video = document.getElementById('video');
          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('face');
          tracker.setInitialScale(4);
          tracker.setStepSize(2);
          tracker.setEdgesDensity(0.1);

          tracking.track('#video', tracker, { camera: true });

          tracker.on('track', function(event) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
              context.strokeStyle = '#a64ceb';
              context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
              context.font = '11px Helvetica';
              context.fillStyle = "#fff";
              context.fillText('x: ' + rect.x + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 11);
              context.fillText('y: ' + rect.y + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 22);
            });
          });

          var gui = new dat.GUI();
          gui.add(tracker, 'edgesDensity', 0.1, 0.5).step(0.01);
          gui.add(tracker, 'initialScale', 1.0, 10.0).step(0.1);
          gui.add(tracker, 'stepSize', 1, 5).step(0.1);
        };
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="demo-container">
          <video id="video" width="920" height="540" preload autoplay loop muted></video>
          <canvas id="canvas" width="920" height="540"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>

       <audio>
      <source src="../audio/multiple_yous.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
     </audio>
      <audio>
      <source src="../audio/is_something_here.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
     </audio>

      <audio>
      <source src="../audio/oh_something_is_here.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
     </audio>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error at the end of your `slowAlert` function.

Comment: What do you mean?